# limits problem-ordinary sencond order equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

we consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 y''+xy'+\lambda y\\
y(1)=y(e)=0
\end{cases}
$$
The question is to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for this problem.

I try to put $y(x)=x^r$ and plug it in the equation, then we obtain the caracteristic equation $$r^2+r+\lambda =0$$
In the case $\lambda >0$ we put $\lambda= \alpha^2$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$. Then the caracteristic equation is 
$$
r^2+\lambda=0
$$

Case 1. If $\lambda >0$ We put $\lambda = \alpha^2$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$. 
Then the genral solution of the equation is 
$$
y(x)=C_1 \cos(\alpha x)+ C_2 \sin(\alpha x).
$$
We have $y(1)=0 => C_1=0$ and $y(e)=0 => C_2 \sin(\alpha e)=0$

$Sin(\alpha e)=0 => \alpha e = \pi + 2 k \pi, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}^\star$

My solution is correct?

Comment: I think that a "$=0$" in your equation is missing.

Comment: See the discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: i don't understand how we distingue the three cases, can you help me please

Comment: Your characteristic equation is wrong. $r(r-1)+r+λ=r^2+λ$.

Comment: i edit my solution. Can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $u(t)=y(e^t)$, then $u'=y'e^t$, 
$$
u''(t)=y''(e^t)e^{2t}+y'(e^t)e^t=-λy(e^t)=-λu(t)
$$
so that you end up with the standard Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem 
$$
u''+λu=0,\ u(0)=0=u(1).
$$

Comment: but this case is when $x >0$ and when $x<0$ what's the solution? Please

Comment: $x$ ranges from $1$ to $e$, is always positive. There is no need to parametrize the negative half-axis.

Comment: can you show me how we finish solution with your method please

Comment: You get the usual solutions $u(t)=\sinh(αt)$ that never satisfy the second boundary condition and $u(t)=\sin(αt)$ that satisfy the second condition for $α=k\pi$.